# OAuth2 Google API

Tags: c#, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for an OAuth2 client API I can use in C#, and I came across Googles:  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

It talks about how to use it to integrate with OAuth for various Google services, but can this library also be used for non-Google OAuth services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* can use for example `OAuth2Authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest()` but it will be tricky and not worth the effort. I would rather suggest taking a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) which supports OAuth2 (and is used by StackOverflow).

Comment: I saw DotNetOpenAuth before, but I thought OAuth2 support was still be beta.  Doesn't seem to be the case anymore though.

Comment: OAuth2 specification itself is in progress so there is some beta-ing anyway. http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/oauth/dotnetopenauth-4-0-released/